# Use Javascript to click a button in a popup

Tags: javascript

On my website I'm trying to make an html page that has JS to go to another page in my site and click a button. Clicking that button creates a popup on which I want to click *another* button. How can I do this?

I know that I can use getElementsByName().click() to click the buttons, but I'm not sure how to go into the popup. Does .click() return a window object for the popup?

I don't have the ability to change these web pages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use selenium...Crawling a web page from another web page makes no sense

Comment: If by popup you mean another page from your browser, and not a modal window, you would need to execute another script from inside this popup to access it. 

Is the popup window on your site as well? You could use a URL parameter or perform a POST request to obtain the information from the first page.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the ability to change the URL or handle a POST.

Comment: @Liam I know it doesn't make sense, but it is necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you load that second page inside of an iframe.

The code will be something like this.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('secondPageIframe');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

var firstButton = innerDoc.getElementById('buttonId');
// This will open the modal
if (typeof firstButton.onclick == "function") {
    firstButton.onclick.apply(firstButton);
}

// Just a delay to be sure that the modal has finished with animations
setTimeout(function() {
   var modalButton = innerDoc.getElementById('modalButtonId');
   if (typeof modalButton.onclick == "function") {
      modalButton.onclick.apply(modalButton);
   }
}, 500);
```

That should do the work, but you must open that page inside of an iframe and this page has to be in the same domain, if not this will be an intent of cross-site scripting.

Comment: You have one page that goes to another page, you can create an iframe and open the second page there. You don't need to change the page that has the modal, just the page where you are running the script.